# Determining a general sequence is bounded and has a particular limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having a hard time with the following problem. I seem to be going around in circles in trying to prove either. Some tips in finding a proof for both would be appreciated.

---

For $n\ge 1$, let $a_n$ be a sequence converging to a limit $A \neq 0$, and let $b_n$ be a sequence such that $a_nb_n$ converges to a limit L.

1. Prove that the sequence $b_n$ is bounded.
2. Prove that $b_n \to L/A$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: You probably meant $b_n \to L/A \, $ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry that is correct.

Comment: $b_n = \dfrac{a_n b_n}{a_n} \,$. What do you know about the quotient of convergent sequences?

Comment: $a_n b_n$ converges to $L$. $a_n$ converges to $A$. Therefore $\displaystyle\frac{a_n b_n}{a_n}$ converges to $\displaystyle\frac{L}{A}$.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. Perhaps the answer is not a lot. I should have mentioned that the problem was given in the context that I shouldn't use any proofs given in class which I took as meaning don't use $lim_{n\to \infty} x_ny_n = ab$ directly.

Comment: It was also said for part 2 that: "For part (2), given $\epsilon > 0$ you should produce $N$ - though not an explicit number - such that $|b_n - L/A| < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you know that if a sequence is convergent then it is bounded (if you have not done this yet then take it as an easy exercise). Now assuming this fact you can proceed as follows.

Since you know that $(a_n)$ is convergent and $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}a_n \neq 0$, it follows that $|a_n| \in [\epsilon,M]$ for some $\epsilon,M > 0$ (because if can not find any $\epsilon >0$ for which this holds then it will mean that $(a_n)$ converges to $0$, which is not true) and the $M$ is coming from the fact that $(a_n)$ is bounded. Therefore, $\frac{1}{|a_n|}\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ for all $n$. By the same argument there will exist $K$ such that $|a_nb_n|\leq K$ for all $n$. Thus, $|b_n| = |\frac{a_nb_n}{a_n}| \leq \frac{K}{\epsilon}$ for all $n$, which shows that $(b_n)$ is bounded.

For the second part the easiest way is to use that $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n} = \frac{\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}x_n}{\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}y_n}$. If you don't want to use this then what you can do is just imitate the proof of this result which you can find in any standard text.

$\textit{Note:}$ I am assuming that all the divisions are permissible, i.e., there are no zero terms in the denominators.

Comment: I am not allowed to assume that a convergent sequence is bounded, or vise-versa. There is a formal proof in my course notes for this but I have been specified that I can't rely on this result directly. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you are not allowed to use that result then just imitate its proof as the the is very basic. This the only way I can think of....Thank You!!!!